# Python - Delete elements from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using the piece of code below to compare two objects while ignoring a few keys. However, the code doesn’t work when I try to delete a field from nested dictionary.
I need to ignore `A` and also `lastElement` from `C`. The below code is able to accomplish ignoring `A` but not `lastElement` from `C`.

**Code**:

```
def equal_dicts(d1, d2, ignore_keys=()):
    d1_, d2_ = d1.copy(), d2.copy()
    for k in ignore_keys:
        try:
            del d1_[k]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            del d2_[k]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return json.dumps(d1_, sort_keys=True) == json.dumps(d2_, sort_keys=True)
```

**Trying to execute the above as**:

```
equal_dicts(data1, data2, ('A', 'C'['lastElement']))
```

**Expected Output**: True.

**data1**:

```
{
    "A": "123456789",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "def"
    },
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "jul"
    }
}
```

**data2**:

```
{
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "jul"
    },
    "A": "78901234",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "e"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not compare the two dicts directly, with `d1_ == d2_`?  Why are you comparing the json string representations?

Comment: Also, the dicts in your code do not have `dateTime` nor `trxId` keys.

Comment: The two dicts might not be in the sorted order. I am looking to compare two dicts excluding “A” and also “lastElement” from C

Comment: Dict comparison does not require them to be in sorted order.

Comment: Dictionaries _in general_ are not in a sorted order. They are compared for the equality of keys and values.

Comment: Putting them in a string might not sort right. Using == won't mess up because of order

Comment: `'C'['lastElement']` is an error.  If you want, you could make up a special syntax like `'C::lastElement'`, which your function could parse to mean "dictionary key `'C'`, which holds another dictionary with key `'lastElement'`.

Comment: @JohnGordon. Then you'd have to split on the separator, which will, according to Murphy's law, be contained in one of your keys. It's easier to just have a tuple of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to delete keys doesn't seem right. Apart from that I have tried to make minimal changes to your code.

```
from functools import reduce
import json

def delete_nested(dictionary, paths):
    """
    Delete the keys specified as path in paths from dictionary.
    """
    for path in paths:
        parent_path, last_key = path[:-1], path[-1]
        parent = reduce(dict.get, parent_path, dictionary)
        if(parent==None):
            sys.exit("The path {path} is invalid".format(path=path))
        if(not(isinstance(parent, dict))):
            sys.exit("The path {path} doesn't contain a dict".format(path=parent_path))

        del parent[last_key]

def equal(d1, d2, ignore_keys=[]):
    """
    Check if d1 and d2 are equal less the ignore_keys
    """
    d1_, d2_ = d1.copy(), d2.copy()
    delete_nested(d1_, ignore_keys)
    delete_nested(d2_, ignore_keys)
    return d1_ == d2_
```

Example execution:

```
d1 = json.loads("""{
    "A": "123456789",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "def"
    },
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "jul"
    }
}""")

d2 = json.loads("""{
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "jul"
    },
    "A": "78901234",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "e"
    }
}""")

print(equal(d1, d2, ["A",["B","lastElement"]])) # prints True
```

Answer (score 1):

A big part of the problem is that you don't have a proper spec for nested keys. You obviously can't index a string with another string, so `'C'['lastElement']` won't give you anything but an error. Let's use a tuple or other iterable to hold nested keys:

```
equal_dicts(data1, data2, ('A', ('C', 'lastElement')))
```

Now it should be pretty easy to clean up the dictionaries:

```
def remove_key(d, k):
    if not isinstance(d, dict): return
    try:
        if isinstance(k, str) or len(k) == 1:
            if not isinstance(k, str): k = k[0]
            del d[k]
        else:
            remove_key(d[k[0]], k[1:])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Just use this function instead of `del`.

Keep in mind that the copy you made is shallow: deleting nested keys will actually remove them from the original objects as well. You can counteract that by updating the `remove_key` function to return an updated dictionary as necessary only when you delete a key. This won't be much cheaper than making a deep copy most likely, but it should be a bit easier to read:

```
def remove_key(d, key):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    if not isinstance(key, str):
        key, *rem = key
    else:
        rem = []
    if key not in d:
        return d
    if not rem:
        return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != key}
    e = remove_key(d[key], rem)
    if e is not d[key]:
         return {k: e if k == key else v for k, v in d.items()}
    return d
```

Use this version to assign the copies:

```
for key in ignore_keys:
    d1 = remove_key(d1, key)
    d2 = remove_key(d2, key)
```

If no key is removed, these will just stay as the original references. Any removed key will trigger a copy only of the necessary levels of the nested dictionary, although this may happen multiple times for a given level.

For your final return value, just use `return d1 == d2`. Dictionary comparison is done by actual key and value without any regard for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to delete keys from the nested dictionaries. Below is a working example.

```
import json


def update_dict(original_dict, keys):
    return_dict = original_dict.copy()

    for k in keys:
        if isinstance(k, dict):
            _key = list(k.keys())[0]
            return_dict[_key] = update_dict(original_dict[_key], k.values())
        else:
            try:
                del return_dict[k]
            except KeyError:
                pass
    return return_dict


def equal_dicts(d1, d2, ignore_keys=()):
    d1_, d2_ = update_dict(d1, ignore_keys), update_dict(d2, ignore_keys)
    return json.dumps(d1_, sort_keys=True) == json.dumps(d2_, sort_keys=True)


data1 = {
    "A": "123456789",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "def"
    },
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "abc"
    }
}

data2 = {
    "A": "78901234",
    "B": {
        "firstElement": "abc",
        "lastElement": "def"
    },
    "C": {
        "firstElement": "chi",
        "lastElement": "jul"
    }
}

print(equal_dicts(data1, data2, ('A', 'dateTime', 'trxId', {'C':'lastElement'})))
```

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but you can now pass in a dictionary. It will only delete the keys in that dictionary from the expected parent.

Comment: This is unsafe because there may be a 'lastElement' in another subdictionary.

Comment: I updated the code to allow passing keys in a dictionary. Now it should properly handle only deleting elements from the correct subdictionary.